# How do I get this Many_to_Many Association To Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have what I thought was a fairly simple many to many association that I'm trying to get working. I can get to the join table from both sides but I can't get through the join table to the other side. I have three models: Jockey, Starter and Races.  The models follows:

```
class Jockey < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :starters
has_many :races, :through => :starters
end

class Starter < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :race
belongs_to :jockey
end

class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :starters
has_many :jockeys, :through => :starters
end
```

When I do this:

```
Jockey.find(1).starters  # everything works great
```

and when i do this:

```
Race.find(1).starters # everything works great
```

but if I try this

Race.find(1).starters.jockeys  or Jockeys.find(1).starters.races

I get errors:

```
    `Jockey Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "jockeys".* FROM "jockeys" WHERE "jockeys"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
    NoMethodError:   Starter Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "starters".* FROM "starters" WHERE
 `"starters"."jockey_id" = 1undefined method `races' for


    #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x4de89831>
```

I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of hours now, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.   Any guidances would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind `Jockeys.find(1)` is this sql:

```
SELECT "jockeys".* FROM "jockeys" WHERE "jockeys"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

ie now you have a concrete Jockey object

But when you do `Jockeys.find(1).starters.races`, you are really calling the races method on the ActiveRecord::Relation instance (as the error message indicates), and not on a concrete Starter instance, as you should. And if you think about it, `starters.races` really does not make sense - on what object are you calling the races method?

So you should call it like so:

```
Jockeys.find(1).starters.first.races
```

`.first` gets you a concrete Starter object, on which you can call the races method

But since you declared that Jockey has_many :races (through the starters join table), the easiest way to get all races for a particular jockey is, of course, this:

```
Jockeys.find(1).races
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked. One question however, the way this is structured, won't the query always return one record.  Supposed I am interested in retrieving all the races for that Jockey.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that startrs is not a Starter object,  it's a relation/collection, you need to fetch the object in it first.
e.g.

```
Race.find(1).starters.first.jockey
```

Comment: Race.find(1).starters.first.jockey worked.  I am confused though, because I have other models with the same association structure and I am able to do Race.find(1).starters.jockeys.